# .Net Application Settings - Property Binding OnPropertyChanged()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, .net-3.5

I have a property on a label bound to a Setting in my App Setting file.  What I am wondering,

Can I hook a `OnPropertyChanged()` up to this some how?

I know there are other ways I may accomplish this but this got my curiosity up so I thought I'd ask.

### EDIT

The reason I am asking is when the bound property of my label - `Tag(bool)` changes I want to switch the `Text` property of that same label.  I was hoping I could use `OnPropertyChanged()` for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you have a custom implementation of the settings class? What are you trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: No, just your typical Settings.settings file in a winform app that has it's scope set to User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the Visual Studio settings designer to create custom settings values, the designer-generated class derives from [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) which does implement INotifyPropertyChanged already. So data binding should pick up changes to the properties without any effort on your part. Is this not happening?

Comment: No, no, I had no idea that was how it worked and as such may have jumped the gun.